# Webview causes ANR

Tags: android, android-webview, android-anr-dialog

I have written an app which displays html pages in Webviews, which are managed in a ViewPager. All working ok, but I have had a few ANRs when swiping from one page to another. The ANR data dump shows that the main thread has called through ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame() which calls a native method, which apparently communicates with the Renderer thread, and waits for that thread to complete drawing the view. Since both of these are executing native code it's hard to work out what's going on but it appears the Renderer thread has never signalled the main thread to resume, hence causing the ANR. There is nothing in the logcat prior to the ANR report that suggests any problem.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to troubleshoot this? I am assuming that the call to ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame() is associated with the Webview, but I don't actually have anything to confirm that.

The problem is not repeatable, in the sense that if I restart the app and navigate to the same page that was showing when the ANR occurred, it doesn't happen again. Device is a Nexus 7 running Android 5.1.

ANR stacktrace for main and renderer threads:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x73547000 self=0xb4827800
| sysTid=1248 nice=-6 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fd6bec
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6035 stm=1406 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0xbe5a6000-0xbe5a8000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/1248/stack)
native: #00 pc 000133b8 /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
native: #01 pc 00016a81 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative(pthread_cond_t*, pthread_mutex_t*, timespec const*)+56)
native: #02 pc 0003c73b /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
native: #03 pc 0003c771 /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
native: #04 pc 0083fd83 /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_view_ThreadedRenderer_nSyncAndDrawFrame__JJJF+134)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:340)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

"RenderThread" prio=5 tid=26 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c07820 self=0xa1c30800
| sysTid=1303 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa1c44c00
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=8314 stm=1817 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0xa0cc2000-0xa0cc4000 stackSize=1012KB
| held mutexes=
kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/1303/stack)
native: #00 pc 000133b8 /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
native: #01 pc 0001741b /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_wait_ex+42)
native: #02 pc 00017761 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+230)
native: #03 pc 0001d767 /system/vendor/lib/libgsl.so (os_mutex_lock+6)
native: #04 pc 0001ea88 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so (egliDoDestroyEGLImage+180)
native: #05 pc 0008698d /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (rb_image_try_release+32)
native: #06 pc 00086acf /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (rb_destroy_resource_updates_pure+136)
native: #07 pc 00085491 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (rb_perform_resolve+276)
native: #08 pc 00085761 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (rb_resolve+464)
native: #09 pc 0008a891 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (rb_surface_swap+228)
native: #10 pc 0006af89 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (gl2_surface_swap+76)
native: #11 pc 0005d12b /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (oglSwapBuffer+194)
native: #12 pc 00013ddc /system/vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so (qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers+1776)
native: #13 pc 00007b60 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so (eglSwapBuffers+16)
native: #14 pc 0001237f /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglSwapBuffers+290)
native: #15 pc 0003d291 /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
native: #16 pc 0003bd05 /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
native: #17 pc 0003beb5 /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
native: #18 pc 0003caed /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
native: #19 pc 0003e743 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+66)
native: #20 pc 000104d5 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+112)
native: #21 pc 0005f839 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+72)
native: #22 pc 00010045 /system/lib/libutils.so (???)
native: #23 pc 00016baf /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
native: #24 pc 00014af3 /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue and I can reproduce it only with a Nexus 7 when there are many large items in the ViewPager

Comment: @Tughi No solution as yet, but I also notice it only happens after paging a relatively large number of Fragments in the ViewPager. I have just made some changes to my FragmentStatePagerAdapter implementation and will see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Clyde Can you explain what your changes are and are they helpful? I had the same issue on my devices. The solution to uninstall the WebView updates can only be a temporal solution.

Comment: Recent updates to the Webview component appear to have made this problem go away.

Comment: I'm getting basically this same stack trace reported occasionally in the ANRS & Crashes in the play console. I wish I could figure it out

Answer (score 5):

It may be a bug on Android 7.0 WebView, you can fix it by two ways below:

1、webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

2、android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Comment: May I ask the reason why that above approach works ?

Comment: Perfect,My device is Android 6.0,webview is load normally after removing webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

Answer (score 2):

I faced with this issue too Seems that Chromium bug, that is related with latest Chromium Webview 43.0.23567.121. You could try to rollback webview on your app and check it again. For me issue reproducable only at latest Webview version.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a `driver` and `chromium` bug, see
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501901